# Thymeleaf templates erro no Heroku

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku, thymeleaf

Eu implementei minha aplicação no Heroku, apenas para testes... Localmente tudo funciona bem, mas no Heroku depois que eu faço login com as credenciais eu sou direcionado para a página `sac/index`, o que é o correto, mas me retorna:

> "Whitelabel Error Page
>
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing
>   this as a fallback.
>
> Tue May 30 19:56:32 UTC 2017 There was an unexpected error
>   (type=Internal Server Error, status=500). Error resolving template
>   "/sac/index", template might not exist or might not be accessible by
>   any of the configured Template Resolvers"

Porém, quando eu acesso outra página como `/sac/listUsers` funciona normalmente.

Esse é o meu Controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/sac/index")
public ModelAndView home(){
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    User user = userService.findUserByEmail(auth.getName());
    modelAndView.addObject("userName", user.getName() + " (" + user.getEmail() + ")");
    modelAndView.setViewName("/sac/index");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

Minha configuração http:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {      
    http.
        authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()              
            .antMatchers("/sac/registration").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/sac/consultarUsuarios").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/sac/index").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN", "SUPPORT")
            .antMatchers("/sac/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN", "SUPPORT").anyRequest()                
            .authenticated().and().csrf().disable().formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error=true")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/sac/index")
            .usernameParameter("email")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .and().logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login").and().exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");
}
```

Pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
```

Application.properties:

```
# ===============================
# = Thymeleaf configurations
# ===============================
spring.thymeleaf.enabled=true
spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=true
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5
spring.thymeleaf.encoding=UTF-8
spring.thymeleaf.content-type=text/html
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
```

Alguém sabe o que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow in Portuguese. In case you haven't noticed, this is the SO Portuguese community, if you're looking to get help in english please visit the [SO English Community](http://stackoverflow.com/questions). If you're looking to get help in portuguese, please edit and translate your question.

Comment: @ramaral I'm sorry, I didn't saw that T_T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ontem um usuário que infelizmente não lembro o nick respondeu e me deu a solução. Infelizmente o mesmo excluiu o comentário. Então fica aqui meu agradecimento!

A solução dada por este usuário foi retirar a primeira "/" da seguinte linha no meu controller:

Antes:

```
modelAndView.setViewName("/sac/index");
```

Depois:

```
modelAndView.setViewName("sac/index");
```

Comment: Fui eu, tive o mesmo problema, mas não tinha certeza se era isso, por isso removi o comentário

Comment: @DenisRudneideSouza era exatamente o que você tinha falado, salvou minha vida cara!!! Obrigado! hahahaha